Validation of Sparse CCA and Kernel CCA on Small Datasets
I have a small dataset with sizes (257, 89) and (257, 289). I have experimented with various sparse CCA and kernel CCA methods but am struggling with validation.
To assess the effectiveness of my approaches, I calculate the maximum absolute difference in the correlation matrix before and after testing, using the canonical variables obtained through 1⋅ and x2⋅V. Despite trying multiple methods, none have successfully validated through 10-fold cross-validation.
I noticed that while training, correlation increases to around 98, and in some cases, test data correlation has increased by 7-fold. However, I cannot achieve consistent validation, even when adjusting sparsity and regularization parameters.
Could my validation approach be flawed? What are some reliable methods to validate the effectiveness of my KCCA and sparse CCA implementations? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
I expected to see improvements in the correlation between my canonical variables and the original features after applying these methods. My goal was to achieve higher correlation values, ideally showing that the canonical variables effectively captured the relationships between the datasets.
